# Some Fonts Do Not Work Properly With `multicols` and `babel`

Tags: babel, multicolumn, right-to-left, ebgaramond, junicode

I initially posted this on the [EB Garamond](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/issues/149) repository, but was suggested to ask it here instead. This is an issue that occurs with only two fonts that I tried: EB Garamond and Junicode Two Beta. If you try to use a right-to-left language like Arabic with `babel` and put English and Arabic text in a `multicols` environment, the result will be incorrect if there is a paragraph end before `\end{otherlanguage}`. The reason I wanted to put a paragraph end before `\end{otherlanguage}` is as a workaround for an [issue](https://github.com/michal-h21/linebreaker/issues/7) with the linebreaker package. All of the pages with the exception of the last one will be shifted far to the left. What confuses me is why this only happens with some fonts.

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol, lipsum, linebreaker}
\usepackage[bidi = basic]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import]{english}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}

\babelfont[english]{rm}{EB Garamond}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1-6]

    \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
        لكن لا بد أن أوضح لك أن كل هذه الأفكار المغلوطة حول استنكار  النشوة وتمجيد الألم
        نشأت بالفعل، وسأعرض لك التفاصيل لتكتشف حقيقة وأساس تلك السعادة البشرية، فلا أحد
        يرفض أو يكره أو يتجنب الشعور بالسعادة، ولكن بفضل هؤلاء الأشخاص الذين لا يدركون بأن
        السعادة لا بد أن نستشعرها بصورة أكثر عقلانية ومنطقية فيعرضهم هذا لمواجهة الظروف
        الأليمة، وأكرر بأنه لا يوجد من يرغب في الحب ونيل المنال ويتلذذ بالآلام، الألم هو الألم
        ولكن نتيجة لظروف ما قد تكمن السعاده فيما نتحمله من كد وأسي.

    \end{otherlanguage}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit:** As @Mico points out, what causes this issue is not actually the paragraph end before `\end{otherlanguage}`. It is caused by the fact that there is a page break right before the `otherlanguage` part.

Comment: The plot thickens: I think the real culprit isn't the fact that there's a blank line (which generates a paragraph break) at the end of the `otherlanguage` environment. Instead, it would appear to be the fact that there's a page break immediately before the start of the `otherlanguage` section. To verify this, replace `\lipsum[1-6]` with either `\lipsum[1-5]` or `\lipsum[1-7]` and recompile. Either way, there's a problem.

Comment: Without `linebreaker` it works as expected if there are no pars. However, it should work even if pars are added. So, there is an issue with `babel` as well as some bad interactions between the three packages. I’ve opened an issue: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/228

Comment: as shown starting from here https://github.com/michal-h21/linebreaker/issues/7#issuecomment-1469845271the false/broken alignments also occurs even

- without `multicol` and
- without `linebreaker` package

simply using basic `\twocolumn`

Comment: @amarakon Please, can edit your post to add a link to the issue in `linebreaker`? I wasn’t aware of it and it is very relevant. @hpvd Thank you for the pointer, but a report in the `babel` tracker would have been useful.

Comment: @JavierBezos I made the requested edit.

Comment: there was a fix in linebreaker package yesterday https://github.com/michal-h21/linebreaker/issues/7
and in babel today https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/228
When both were officially released to ctan, we can see if it solves the issue completely...

Comment: It does solve it completely.

Answer (score 1):

as described in comments above, there are updates available for babel and linebreaker package (not on ctan yet but on github) which solves this issue as confirmed by @amarakon